# Make WordPress run everything BUT the homepage

Tags: wordpress

We're launching an online application which is basically nothing but a static `index.php` with a Flash embed in it. We also want to add an FAQ page and a blog. So in addition to `https://www.example.com` (the application), we'll have the `https://www.example.com/faq` static page and `https://www.example.com/blog`.

The FAQ and the blog can be run by a WordPress installation but we'd like to keep the application itself running from our simple `index.php` (to avoid the WP overhead, for one thing). The question is, is it possible to install WP in such a way that the homepage is run by our original `index.php` but everything else is either WP static pages or the blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is using `.htaccess` to make a file like `home.php` as the default index page. That would work best and would let you keep upgrading wordpress normally.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: Alternatively use index.html if you are serving static pages. Or you could rewrite .htacess to use index2.php (renaming the original index.php to index2.php or something) as the RewriteRule. But that would be a pain at upgrades.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. We'll probably go for making `home.php` the default index page.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand why you would need wordpress for such a "static" site, but anyhow, one solution could be to install index.php in the root ( e.g. `http://www.myapp.com` )  and then give wp it´s own folder ( `http://www.myapp.com/wp/` ), but maintaining the blogurl and homeurl as that subfolder (  `http://www.myapp.com/wp/` ).

In this way you would have actually 2 indexes, one of your main application (  `http://www.myapp.com/index.php` ) , and one in the subfolder (  `http://www.myapp.com/wp/index.php` ).

They will operate as total different application easily linked .

There are of course a ton of other ways to do it , ( for example just make a special `home.php` template file - while not eliminating the index the result will be the same  ) or just define that other page as a static home page , or with redirects... all depends on what exactly you want to achieve and how ..

Comment: As mentioned in the question, there will be a blog, so it makes sense to use WordPress for the static pages like the FAQ, too.

Comment: Using what I wrote you could use whatever you want , you will have a full blown working wordpress that you can use to whatever you want . Changing the default in  .htaccess like mentioned is also a viable possibility , but it would most probably hurt your SEO ..

Answer (score 1):

While the solution in the accepted answer works, it causes URLs such as `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/` lead to 404 errors. The problem here is that any statements within Apache's `Directory` directive also apply to subdirectories. So if I set

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

on my website's dir, then `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/` will also implicitly reference the non-existing `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/home.php`.

The solution that worked for me is actually quite simple and required minimum modifications to the .htaccess generated by WordPress itself:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^$ /home.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The important bit here is line #4 where I insert `RewriteRule ^$ /home.php [L]`. That's it!